# GPU PoolAllocator explodes the CPU memory

Tags: memory, tensorflow, cpu, cpu-usage

I made a tensorflow model with relatively common operations (apart from a couple of `tf.where` and indices handling), but call it with very varying different input shapes (many undefined tensor shapes in the model).

Everything works fine on the CPU. **But when you use the GPU**, the RAM usage (not the GPU memory, the CPU one) steadily increases up to fill the 256GB of the machine and kills itself.

During the process, I get the usual messages :

```
2017-03-17 16:42:22.366601: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 18347 get requests, put_count=18345 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.0545108 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.0763068
2017-03-17 16:42:22.366680: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 4385 to 4823
```

Which as far as I understand is the pool allocator for some DMA memory for the GPU. The problem is that it seems to never be satisfied with the eviction rate it gets and never ends allocating more space for itself.

Is this normal behavior? Are they ways to control this? Right now, **I can not train a model for longer than 1h before running out of memory**.

Note: I use the nigthly build version of TF, because of some bugfixes necessary for my current model to run. Also, no operations are added during training because I called `tf.get_default_graph().finalize()`

**EDIT :** tried to run with `tcmalloc` instead of `malloc`. Did not help. I also used the memory profiler and it is not saying there is a memory leak, memory usage stabilizing at 500MB for tcmalloc even if the memory usage in `top` is way higher and the program eventually run OOM.
So why is the `tcmalloc` profiler not agreeing with the memory usage I see in `top`?

**EDIT 2 :** recompiled TF with changed hardcoded params to make it "work". See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8560)

Comment: Looks like a memory leak, have you taken a look at [this topic in the documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/3883/how-to-debug-a-memory-leak-in-tensorflow/13426/use-graph-finalize-to-catch-nodes-being-added-to-the-graph) ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was already careful of not adding nodes during execution with `finalize`. Will have a look at this tcmalloc alternative.

Comment: I don't know what's causing your issue, but the answer to "is this normal" is clearly "no"

Comment: In the end I managed to get away with it by recompiling TF with changing the hard-coded parameters of the PoolAllocator. I posted a Github Issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8560) about it but I guess the poor TF devs are flooded with them...

Comment: For people getting the same symptoms but having not necessarily the same causes. You should also finalize your graph before training, i.e. `sess.graph.finalize()`. I forgot it once and TF happily allocated new memory over and over (it was a bug in my python code) causing the issue after a few iterations. For debugging you can also set `TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific problem was solved some times ago by the TF team when they changed their memory allocator (see the [Corresponding issue on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8560)).

If you encounter a growth in memory during training, a common mistake is that nodes are being added to the graph during the training (TF is not numpy, unless you use eager execution). Make sure to call [`graph.finalize()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#finalize) before your training loop to ensure no nodes are added during the training process, this allows to catch many memory growth issues.